# compare comma separated values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I am trying to write a function to compare comma separated values in SQL
I've taken some code from Internet :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Split(@v1)
  WHERE ', ' + LTRIM(@v2) + ',' 
  LIKE '%, ' + LTRIM(Item) + ',%'
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Then I make a function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCompareCSVString] 
(   
    @str1 nvarchar(50),
    @str2 nvarchar(50)
)

RETURNS  int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (
       SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Split(@str1)
       WHERE ', ' + LTRIM(@str2) + ',' 
         LIKE '%, ' + LTRIM(Item) + ',%'
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END
```

I am not good in SQL I know this is wrong

## Question:

I want to write a function for comparing comma separated values that will take two values (comma separated values) after comparison the return value will be true or false

What changes I have to do in this SQL function  ?

Comment: See if you can state a clear question.  Some example input and output help clarify your query.  I know many SO veterans ask for "what have you tried", but that information is not actually useful, so list it at the end if you feel you have to.

Comment: If you don't know SQL very well, you should change your data structure so you are storing strings in a more SQL-compatible way (i.e. one row per value in the string, multiple rows to represent a string).  Hmmm, even if you do know SQL well, that would be useful.

Comment: Do you want a list of differences or matches between the two CSV lists?

Comment: Hi Kane ...I want to matches between two CSV if any one match then return true else false

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

**True / False results**

```
-- matches only those values which exist in both CSV sets
SELECT T1.[Item], CASE  WHEN T2.[Item] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [Match] 
FROM [dbo].[Split]('val1,val2,val3', ',') AS T1
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Split]('val3,val4', ',') AS T2 on T1.[Item] = T2.[Item]
```

Returns

```
Item    Match
val1    0
val2    0
val3    1
```

**Only true matches**

```
-- matches only those values which exist in both CSV sets
SELECT T1.[Item] 
FROM [dbo].[Split]('val1,val2,val3', ',') AS T1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Split]('val3,val4', ',') AS T2 on T1.[Item] = T2.[Item]
```

Returns

```
Item
val3
```

**Split function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] 
(   
    @s VARCHAR(max),
    @split CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @temptable TABLE ([Item] VARCHAR(MAX))    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x XML

    SELECT @x = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@s,@split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>');

    INSERT INTO @temptable          
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c);
RETURN
END;
```

Comment: I want split ,compare then return true or false in one function I want to use this function in stored procedure

Comment: I will pass two parameter as str1(comma separated values) and str2 (comma separated values)

Comment: Hi Kane , thanks for help ....This will help me but According to our requirement I cant modify your code because I am not good in SQL .... In my Stored procedure I have to compare two CSV string then if any one is matching then return true else false ......So I want to write a function ....As I written in my Question

Comment: This is working fine ...Can any one convert this SP in SQL function and return true or false ( now returning matching word)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @user_ids NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'203616, 198667, 193718, 188769, 183820, 178871, 173922, 168973, 164024, 159075, 154126, 149177, 144228, 139279, 134330, 129381, 124432, 119483, 114534, 109585, 104636, 99687, 94738, 89789, 84840, 79891, 74942, 69993, 65044, 60095, 55146'
 
DECLARE @sql_xml XML = Cast('<root><U>'+ Replace(@user_ids, ',', '</U><U>')+ '</U></root>' AS XML)
    
SELECT f.x.value('.', 'BIGINT') AS user_id
INTO #users
FROM @sql_xml.nodes('/root/U') f(x)
    
SELECT * 
FROM #users
```

[image: Table Image]