# Compare 2 columns value in a table and show the matching values in a new column . column values are comma seperated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, compare

Here I want to compare the comma-separated values from the column roles and userroles, then show the matching values in another column.

I found an example [compare comma separated values in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653163/compare-comma-separated-values-in-sql) and used the cursor to iterate rows one by one. it's working for me. but I feel there should be a better way to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Create table #temp4
(
 user_id int,
 permission_id int, 
 roles varchar(max), 
 userroles varchar(max), 
 matchingrolesinthisrow varchar(max))

Insert Into #temp4 values 
( 1, -12010, '2341,8760,3546', '1000,1001,1002,1003', null),
( 1, -334,   '1002,1001,3467',      '2341,1002,3467', null),
( 2, -12349, '9876,9982,6548', '1001,1002,2341', null)
```

below is the result table I am looking for.

| user_id | permission_id | roles | userroles | matchingrolesinthisrow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -12010 | 2341,8760,3546 | 1000,1001,1002,1003 |  |
| 1 | -334 | 1002,1001,3467 | 2341,1002,3467 | 1002,3467 |
| 2 | -12349 | 9876,9982,6548 | 1001,1002,2341 |  |

My attempt so far and it's working. please guide me to do this in a better way.

```
DECLARE @user_id INT
DECLARE @permission_id INT
DECLARE @roles VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @userroles VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @matchingrolesinthisrow VARCHAR(MAX)
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
    select user_id, permission_id, roles, userroles, matchingrolesinthisrow  from #temp4 order by 1
 
open cur
 
fetch next from cur into @user_id, @permission_id, @roles, @userroles, @matchingrolesinthisrow
 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
 
 print (@roles)
 print(@userroles)
    --execute  on each row 
    UPDATE #temp4 
    SET matchingrolesinthisrow = T1.[Item] 
    FROM [developers].[Split](@roles, ',') AS T1
    INNER JOIN [developers].[Split](@userroles, ',') AS T2 on T1.[Item] = T2.[Item]
    Where roles = @roles and userroles = @userroles and permission_id = @permission_id and user_id = @user_id

    fetch next from cur into @user_id, @permission_id, @roles, @userroles, @matchingrolesinthisrow
END
 
close cur
deallocate cur



--Split function
CREATE FUNCTION [developers].[Split] 
(   
    @s VARCHAR(max),
    @split CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @temptable TABLE ([Item] VARCHAR(MAX))    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x XML

    SELECT @x = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@s,@split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>');

    INSERT INTO @temptable          
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c);
RETURN
END;
```

Comment: @DaleK added my attempt and still trying. I am sure I am not solving this in an efficient way. there should be a better approach.

Comment: @DaleK I updated my attempt and it's working for me so far. is there a better way to achieve this? any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your SQL Server 2016 or newer?

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu sql server 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should store each inidividual piece of information in separate row, so you should have two separate tables `roles` and `userroles` which are foreign-keyed on this one.

Be that as it may, this does not need cursors. You can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` to get the result you want very easily:

```sql
SELECT
  t4.user_id,
  t4.permission_id,
  t4.roles,
  t4.userroles,
  matchingrolesinthisrow = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(r.value, ',')
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t4.roles, ',') r
    JOIN STRING_SPLIT(t4.userroles, ',') ur ON ur.value = r.value
  )
FROM #temp4 t4;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2155a/1)

If you are on an early version of SQL Server, you will have to use custom Table Valued Functions to do this.

Comment: A fiddle to confirm: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2155a/1

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks very much. for the lower version, I used STUFF FOR XML instead STRING_AGG and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Modified the shared answer to work in the lower version of SQL Server.

```
SELECT
  t4.user_id,
  t4.permission_id,
  t4.roles,
  t4.userroles, 
 STUFF((SELECT N',' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2000),r.value) 
 FROM STRING_SPLIT(t4.roles, ',') r
 INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(t4.userroles, ',') ur ON ur.value = r.value
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') as matchingrolesinthisrow
FROM #temp4 t4;
```